# VueJS changing URL params from v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, query-string, v-model

newbie in coding here.

I have to call an API in which I have to change some parts of the querystring to retrieve different results

Briefly explained:

```
<template>
      <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="param" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="param2" />
      </div>
</template>
```

This would modify the following URL in the script zone:

http://localhost:7000/mock?mockingCode=${param}&mockingCode2=[B]${param2}

Comment: Is the API you wish to call on localhost (it looks like from the URL)? Are you using Axios to make that call?

Comment: you cannot have 2 divs next to eatch other inside a template

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what computed is for:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

```
    computed: {
        url() {
            return `http://localhost:7000/mock?mockingCode=${this.param}&mockingCode2=[B]${this.param2}`;
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `watch()`:

```js
data() {
  return {
    param: '',
    param: '',
    url: 'http://localhost:7000/mock?',
  }
}
watch() {
  param() {
    this.url += '`mockingCode=${this.param}&`';
  }
  param() {
    this.url += '`mockingCode2=[B]${this.param2}&`';
  }
}
```